# Missing values in the dataset after using pivot function?

Tags: r, pivot, na

I can not explain why but when I try to `pivot_wider` the dataset every country except the first one suddenly loose all values.

```
corona_data <- read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/covid-19/master/data/time-series-19-covid-combined.csv")
glimpse(corona_data)

corona_data_tidy1 <- corona_data %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(`Country/Region`, Date, Lat, Long, `Province/State`), names_to = "Name", values_to = "values") 

corona_data_tidy1

corona_data_tidy2 <- corona_data_tidy1 %>% 
  
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
pivot_wider(names_from = `Country/Region`, values_from = values) %>%
  select(-row)

corona_data_tidy2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two mistakes in your code.

First of all, `read_csv` returns some warnings.
`Province/State` is read as `logical` instead of `character`. That's because the first 1000 rows are missing. So you should tell `read_csv` how to properly read your data.

The problem related to your question is that one row is not defined by just `Country/Region`, but by `Country/Region` and `Province/State`. Lat and Long are also uniquely identified for each couple `Country/Region` and `Province/State`.

Therefore if you want to keep those info, you need to use them all in the pivot.

Look at this working example:

```
library(readr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

corona_data <- readr::read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/covid-19/master/data/time-series-19-covid-combined.csv",
                               col_types = cols(
                                Date = col_date(format = ""),
                                `Country/Region` = col_character(),
                                `Province/State` = col_character(),
                                Lat = col_double(),
                                Long = col_double(),
                                Confirmed = col_double(),
                                Recovered = col_double(),
                                Deaths = col_double()))
glimpse(corona_data)

corona_data_tidy1 <- corona_data %>% 
 pivot_longer(c(Confirmed, Recovered, Deaths), names_to = "Name", values_to = "values") 

corona_data_tidy2 <- corona_data_tidy1 %>% 
 pivot_wider(names_from = c(`Country/Region`, `Province/State`, Lat, Long), values_from = values)
```

Comment: I guess it depends what you need to do with your analysis... however, I believe that `corona_data_tidy1` is probably the best dataset for data analysis. `corona_data_tidy2` is too messy.